# Is this NDA terminated after the date shown?

Tags: contract-law, intellectual-property, ownership, non-compete, non-disclosure

I have signed an NDA between my company and another company. I realized that their approach does not fit with my vision and I told them nicely that I am not willing to partner nor sell the company.

I have multiple question regarding this: 
1: I was the only one to sign the NDA, their company did not sign it. The person who talked to me was not the same guy who's name was at the bottom to be signed by. Does the information they gave me still hold if it was stated by an employee in that company?

2: I looked over the NDA to see if there was any kind of termination on it. I saw this at the end:

```
" The obligations under this Agreement will continue in effect from the date hereof through 20th May, 2017. This Agreement (a) constitutes

the entire agreement of the parties with respect to the subject matter hereof and supersedes all prior or contemporaneous oral or written

agreements, negotiations or representations concerning such subject matter (none of which prior or contemporaneous matters shall be binding on

the parties); (b) shall be governed by the laws in the jurisdiction of the injured Party without regard to its conflict or law’s provisions; (c) may only

be amended by a writing executed by both parties and dated after the date hereof; and (d) shall inure to the benefit of the parties hereto and their

respective successors and assigns, and the obligations under which shall be binding upon the parties and their respective affiliates and associates,

but shall not be assigned or delegated to any other person."
```

Does this mean that after the 20th of may, that the NDA is terminated and they can not tell me an idea is theirs? I am a but confused about what that statement meant.

3: They continue to contact me about saying that some ideas that existed were theirs. I was under the impression that NDA was to protect their companies information like how they do a specific thing. Does NDA also cover an idea (new feature) they want my company to implement (nothing regarding their company)? Given they have not given any facts on how to do it, just a general statement of I want you guys to build this and I will market it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Signatures don't matter, except as a way of indicating that the parties agree to the terms. Since they set the terms, one can assume they agree: *your* signature is important, since that's what signals acceptance on your part. If you add or delete terms, that's a counter-offer and they then would have a sign and return that to you. It does not matter who you talked to, what matters is what the NDA says.

After the 20th of December, the restrictions set out in the NDA are terminated. We cannot tell what those restrictions are so we don't know what things you or they are required to do now, but as of the 21st of Dec. you and they can do anything they want, for example they can't say "You can't use that idea". It is possible that the NDA prohibits you from using general ideas as opposed to just specifics of implementation – it depends on the wording.